# Why is PyAutoGUI not detecting specific cards in a card game

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to make a bot that automatically plays a card game for you. But it's for some reason only detecting the shuffle card and doesn't detect the other ones. My Code:

```
def locateandClick():
    oneheart = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('oneheart.png',  grayscale=False, confidence=0.6)
    tenheart = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('tenheart.png',  grayscale=False, confidence=0.6)
    shuffle = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('shuffle.png',  grayscale=False, confidence=0.6)

    if oneheart and tenheart:
        one = pyautogui.center(oneheart)
        ten = pyautogui.center(tenheart)
        pyautogui.moveTo(ten[0], ten[1])
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
        pyautogui.mouseUp()
        pyautogui.moveTo(one[0], one[1])
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
        pyautogui.mouseUp()

    if not oneheart and not tenheart and shuffle:
       shufflecenter = pyautogui.center(shuffle)
       pyautogui.moveTo(shufflecenter[0], shufflecenter[1])
       pyautogui.mouseDown()
       pyautogui.mouseUp()

while True:
    locateandClick()
```

For some reason it only detects the shuffle card and doesn't detect any other card that I put in (yes I have openCV installed for confidence to work)

Shuffle image and oneheart and tenheart images:

[image: Shuffle Image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Under the hood, PyAutoGUI uses template matching for locateOnScreen. When confidence parameter is used, they use [OpenCV matchTemplate](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) function. To get a good match your template has to be present pixel-for-pixel in the image you are searching. It doesn't work well rotation, scale, or color differences. You can also have trouble with lossy formats (i.e. JPEG) because compression artifacts differ too much between template and image to search.

Comment: Your template images are all different sizes. That's could be the source of your problem. The shuffle image is noticeably smaller than the other two images. Also, it looks like the shading in oneheart vs tenheart is slightly different. If the shading differs much between template and searched image, that will also cause trouble.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your awnsers @bfris! I also tried to make it work with all the same images heights but that didn't work either. Any other methods that might work?

Comment: if template matching doesn't work, you can try [Feature Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html)